# How to read an array from Arduino library?

Tags: c++, arduino

I am using ethernet module to upload data to a server using [Cayenne-Arduino-Library](https://github.com/myDevicesIoT/Cayenne-Arduino-Library) and [arduino_uip](https://github.com/ntruchsess/arduino_uip). I want to read the `myip[]` from [CayenneEthernet.h](https://github.com/myDevicesIoT/Cayenne-Arduino-Library/blob/master/Adapters/BlynkEthernet.h)

**Original:**

```
// DHCP with domain
void begin(const char* auth,
    const char* domain = BLYNK_DEFAULT_DOMAIN,
    uint16_t port = BLYNK_DEFAULT_PORT,
    const byte mac[] = _blynkEthernetMac)
{
    BLYNK_LOG("Here we are");// I added this to find this function.
    ...
    IPAddress myip = Ethernet.localIP();
    BLYNK_LOG("My IP: %d.%d.%d.%d", myip[0], myip[1], myip[2], myip[3]);
}
```

**Edited:**

```
// DHCP with domain
int* begin(const char* auth,
    const char* domain = BLYNK_DEFAULT_DOMAIN,
    uint16_t port = BLYNK_DEFAULT_PORT,
    const byte mac[] = _blynkEthernetMac)
{   
    ...
    IPAddress myip = Ethernet.localIP();
    BLYNK_LOG("My IP: %d.%d.%d.%d", myip[0], myip[1], myip[2], myip[3]);
    return myip;
}
```

**Arduino code:**

```
#define CAYENNE_DEBUG         // Uncomment to show debug messages
#define CAYENNE_PRINT Serial  // Comment this out to disable prints and save space
#include <CayenneDefines.h>
#include <UIPEthernet.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleUIPEthernet.h>
#include <CayenneEthernetClient.h>
#define VIRTUAL_PIN V1
#define VIRTUAL_PIN V0
...
void setup(){
...
  int *A=Cayenne.begin(token);
...
}

void loop(){
...
}
```

**I am getting this error:**

> error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

**Question:**

How can I return the array correctly?

**UPDATE:**
After searching `Cayenne.begin()` is defined on [CayenneEthernetClient.h](https://github.com/myDevicesIoT/Cayenne-Arduino-Library/blob/master/CayenneEthernetClient.h)

```
class CayenneEthernetClient : public CayenneClient
{
public:
    void begin(const char* token, const byte mac[] = NULL)
    {
        BLYNK_LOG("HERE WE ARE 3"); 
        Blynk.begin(token, CAYENNE_DOMAIN, CAYENNE_PORT, GetMACAddress(token, mac));

    }

private:

    const byte* GetMACAddress(const char* token, const byte mac[])
    {
        ...
        return _mac;
    }

    byte _mac[6];
};

CayenneEthernetClient Cayenne;
```

After, this begin function is called on [BlynkProtocol.h](https://github.com/myDevicesIoT/Cayenne-Arduino-Library/blob/master/Blynk/BlynkProtocol.h)

```
private:
    int readHeader(BlynkHeader& hdr);
    uint16_t getNextMsgId();

protected:
    void begin(const char* auth) {
        BLYNK_LOG("HERE WE ARE 2");
        this->authkey = auth;
    }
    bool processInput(void);
```

After, this begin() is called on [BlynkEthernet.h](https://github.com/myDevicesIoT/Cayenne-Arduino-Library/blob/master/Adapters/BlynkEthernet.h)

```
// DHCP with domain
void begin( const char* auth,
            const char* domain = BLYNK_DEFAULT_DOMAIN,
            uint16_t port      = BLYNK_DEFAULT_PORT,
            const byte mac[]   = _blynkEthernetMac)
{
    Base::begin(auth);
    BLYNK_LOG("Getting IP...");
    BLYNK_LOG("HERE WE ARE 1");
    if (!Ethernet.begin((byte*)mac)) {
        BLYNK_FATAL("DHCP Failed!");
    }
    // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
    ::delay(1000);
    this->conn.begin(domain, port);
    IPAddress myip = Ethernet.localIP();
    BLYNK_LOG("My IP: %d.%d.%d.%d", myip[0], myip[1], myip[2], myip[3]);

}
```

And this begin() is called finally on [BlynkArduinoClient.h](https://github.com/myDevicesIoT/Cayenne-Arduino-Library/blob/master/Adapters/BlynkArduinoClient.h)

```
void begin(const char* d, uint16_t p) {
    BLYNK_LOG("HERE WE ARE 9");
    domain = d;
    port = p;
}
```

Output on serial monitor:

> ```
> [75] HERE WE ARE 3
> [76] MAC: FE-9D-D2-DD-A3-A0
> [76] HERE WE ARE 2
> [77] Getting IP...
> [80] HERE WE ARE 1
> [5385] HERE WE ARE 9
> [5386] My IP: 10.42.0.162
> ```

Comment: How is Cayenne defined ?

Comment: I don't know how can i find it?

Comment: Cayenne is not defined on arduino code.

Comment: My guess is that the function you changed is not being called. Probably another begin that returns void is being called. It could be the base class of ethernet i.e. protocol.

Comment: It is called because BLYNK_LOG("Here we are"); prints it on serial monitor. Maybe a void function is calling int* begin(...){}

Comment: You can search for all begin functions in the library add prints to them and see which are called also if any

Comment: Check my update

Comment: ok so now it is clear what has to be done, isn't it ?
You need to change all the `begin`'s that are relevant (starting from `CayenneEthernetClient`) from `void` to return `int*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think It's not a good idea to modify the code or even the API of a library.
My approach here would be to get the IP address the same way the Cayenne library does it: A call to `Ethernet.localIP()`:

```
void setup() {
    Cayenne.begin(token);
    IPAddress myip = Ethernet.localIP();
}
```

P.S.: The error

> void value not ignored as it ought to be

probably occurs because you have only modified one of the **three** overridden `begin()` methods in the `Cayenne` class.